# I want to the customize the wso2 open source code i.e wso2/carbon/apimgt ， what to do

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have wso2 APIM 4.0.0 , I want to the customize the wso2 open source code i.e wso2/carbon/apimgt ， like change its ui to chinese, but i don't know what to do this,  Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can localize the API Publisher and the Developer Portal UI by following this document[1].
[1]. https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/adding-internationalization/

Comment: It doesn't works.  I made a copy of en.json and rename it to ch.json, I changed the key 'Apis.Listing.components.TopMenu.apis' value 'APIs' to chinese like 'API列表'，and restart am server , but doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it works when i change ch.json to zh.json